# Young cactus identification

Tags: identification, cactus

I bought another small cactus today, the sellers in the store were not sure what species it is. My guess is that it is from the genus *Pilocereus*, but it is a wild guess. The height is about 7-8 cm (3 inch). Can anyone ID this one with more certainty?

[image: cactus]